# Concept of shared preference in ionic

Tags: ionic3

Does anyone know, how the concept of shared preference in android, is used in ionic?. I tried a lot but couldn't understood how it is used in ionic.

Comment: would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: @devumani  please check my answer and give me feedback is it work or not?

Comment: @suzan i need to use shared preference concept in ionic for storing username when i successfully sign in to my app. I refered ionic storage concept in ionic doc. But i couldn't understood how i can use the key that i set in login page in home page or any other page

Comment: OK you read my post carefully i already said that how to store data and get data. When user successfully sign in then set  storage.set('username', 'devu mani'). And when you retrive username in any page after sign in then call       storage.get('username').then((val) => {
        console.log('Your age is', val);
      });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ionic we are use ionic storage: [storage doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/)

You can install this plugin using following command

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

npm install --save @ionic/storage
```

Include it in your **app.module.ts** imports:

```
  import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

    // Inside of your @NgModule
    imports: [
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot() // Add this
    ],
```

Then, on the page you're using it on, reference it like this:

```
    constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

      ...

      // set a key/value
      storage.set('name', 'Max');

  // Or to get a key/value pair its key value can get from any page after settting key value
      storage.get('name').then((val) => {
        console.log('Your age is', val);
      });
    }
```

Also you can also use localforage: [enter link description here](https://github.com/localForage/localForage)

Installation localforage:

```
npm install localforage
```

Uses:
injecting

```
import * as localforage from "localforage";
```

Store value

```
 localForage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

Getting value (same page or other page)

```
localforage.getItem('key');
```

Hope you will be helpful

Comment: For a offline capable multi device type storage mechanism you could also use Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: use Firebase Realtime Database without offline is it possible @jaaaawn?

Comment: In Android we store little amount of data using shared preference and in ionic we use native storage or localforage

Comment: To answer the question above, the cordova-sqlite-storage plugin would come close to creating a shared preferences type key-value local storage in Ionic.

Comment: @jaaaawn is my answer helpful or not ??

Comment: @utpaul i saw this ionic storage concept in the ionic doc, but if i have to use this value in other page, how can i do that?

Comment: @devumani i update my answer. If you set key value then you can access its data by using its key in any pages